# Cross-platform way to convert filepath to dot notation?

Tags: python, filepath

If I have a file path from a module like, e.g. `"aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.py"` how would I convert that to `"aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"` in python? Also should work with Windows paths, etc. I thought it should be in `pathlib`, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you need to handle absolute paths as well as relative paths? (If so, how? Where should the package root be assumed to be?) Do you need to handle `.` and `..`? Do you need to handle symlinks and/or Windows shortcuts? For the relative path, are you assuming that the beginning of the given path is the root of the package hierarchy?

Comment: If your paths are as simple as shown then split by slash or backslash and join back by dot.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel all paths are in this (relative) form without `.` or `..`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Also should work with Windows paths, etc. I thought it should be in pathlib, but couldn't find anything.

Assuming that you only have to work with resolved, relative paths (as shown) and that the path encodes the exact package hierarchy that you want:

- the `.with_suffix` method can be used to get rid of the `.py` in a `pathlib.Path`
- `.parts` give you the individual components, which you can then join up.

Thus:

```
>>> path = pathlib.Path('aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.py')
>>> '.'.join(path.with_suffix('').parts)
'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd'
```